# Is it possible to use RabbitMQ direct reply-to feature with a Pika generator consumer in Python?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, generator, pika, consumer

I would like to use the [direct reply-to](https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html) feature of RabbitMQ with the [Pika](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) client library in Python. It works with a *basic* consumer. But it raises the following exception with a *generator* consumer:

> pika.exceptions.ChannelClosedByBroker: (406, 'PRECONDITION_FAILED - fast reply consumer does not exist')

**Is there a way to use the direct reply-to feature with a generator consumer?**

Sample client code using a basic consumer (it works):

```
import pika


def handle(channel, method, properties, body):
    message = body.decode()
    print("received:", message)


connection = pika.BlockingConnection()
channel = connection.channel()

with connection, channel:
    message = "hello"
    channel.basic_consume(queue="amq.rabbitmq.reply-to",
                          on_message_callback=handle, auto_ack=True)
    channel.basic_publish(
        exchange="", routing_key="test", body=message.encode(),
        properties=pika.BasicProperties(reply_to="amq.rabbitmq.reply-to"))
    print("sent:", message)
    channel.start_consuming()
```

Sample client code using a generator consumer (it raises the exception):

```
import pika


def handle(channel, method, properties, body):
    message = body.decode()
    print("received:", message)


connection = pika.BlockingConnection()
channel = connection.channel()

with connection, channel:
    message = "hello"
    channel.basic_publish(
        exchange="", routing_key="test", body=message.encode(),
        properties=pika.BasicProperties(reply_to="amq.rabbitmq.reply-to"))
    print("sent:", message)

    for (method, properties, body) in channel.consume(
            queue="amq.rabbitmq.reply-to", auto_ack=True):
        handle(channel, method, properties, body)
```

*Environment.* — Windows 10, RabbitMQ 3.7.13, CPython 3.7.3, Pika 1.0.1.

*Note.* — Calling the `basic_consume` method *after* the `basic_publish` method in the sample client code using a basic consumer raises the same exception as when using a generator consumer:

```
import pika


def handle(channel, method, properties, body):
    message = body.decode()
    print("received:", message)


connection = pika.BlockingConnection()
channel = connection.channel()

with connection, channel:
    message = "hello"
    channel.basic_publish(
        exchange="", routing_key="test", body=message.encode(),
        properties=pika.BasicProperties(reply_to="amq.rabbitmq.reply-to"))
    print("sent:", message)
    channel.basic_consume(queue="amq.rabbitmq.reply-to",
                          on_message_callback=handle, auto_ack=True)
    channel.start_consuming()
```

Comment: I tried reproducing your scenario, I got no error. Both the cases were working fine.

Comment: @bumblebee What is your environment (OS, Python, Pika versions)?

Comment: `OS` - MacOS Mojave 10.14.5
`Python` - 3.6.3
`Pika` - 1.0.0
`RabbitMQ` - 3.7.10

Comment: @bumblebee I tried on Python 3.6.8 and got the same exception. Could you retry by copying the sample client code using a generator consumer in a file (let's say client.py) and running it with Python (`python client.py`)?

Comment: Alright, I will retry and update you.

Comment: @bumblebee I tried on MacOS 10.14: same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Luke Bakken [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pika-python/rryGk-54FsQ/T1gfo8-qCgAJ), this does the trick:

```
import pika


def handle(channel, method, properties, body):
    message = body.decode()
    print("received:", message)


connection = pika.BlockingConnection()
channel = connection.channel()

with connection, channel:
    message = "hello"
    next(channel.consume(queue="amq.rabbitmq.reply-to", auto_ack=True,
                         inactivity_timeout=0.1))
    channel.basic_publish(
        exchange="", routing_key="test", body=message.encode(),
        properties=pika.BasicProperties(reply_to="amq.rabbitmq.reply-to"))
    print("sent:", message)

    for (method, properties, body) in channel.consume(
            queue="amq.rabbitmq.reply-to", auto_ack=True):
        handle(channel, method, properties, body)
```

Answer (score -1):

i would recommend the example given with the pika documentation.

it did work for me too.

[this is the location](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/direct_reply_to.html)